# Javascript setting object property inside object callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set an object (summary) inside another object's callback method

```
returnObj.beforeLoadComplete = function (records) {
    var someObj = {
        total: {
            label: 'Items',
            value: '15'
        },
        additional: [{
            label: 'Item1 Total',
            value: '25000'
        }]
    };

    returnObj.summary = summaryObj;
    // some other code which finally returns an object
}
```

The above code does not work (i.e. `summary` is not set on `returnObj`)

However if I have the same code outside the callback method, it works as in code snippet below:

```
var someObj = {
    total: {
        label: 'Items',
        value: '15'
    },
    additional: [{
        label: 'Item1 Total',
        value: '25000'
    }]
};

returnObj.summary = summaryObj;
returnObj.beforeLoadComplete = function (records) {
    // some other code which finally returns an object
}
```

Not sure why is it so.

Comment: At what point are you checking if it's set?  Could be a [dupe of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)?

Comment: What is the API here?

Comment: i am checking after the callback method get's executed

Comment: you mean returnObj.summary = someObj  ?

Comment: how `returnObj` is defined ? is it global ?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to say this.summary = summaryObj;

Answer (score 5):

You have to access your object with [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) statement, also i've correct some typo:

```
var returnObj = {};
returnObj.beforeLoadComplete = function (records) {
    var someObj = {
        total: {
            label: 'Items',
            value: '15'
        },
        additional: [{
            label: 'Item1 Total',
            value: '25000'
        }]
    };
    // Access object with this
    this.summary = someObj;
    // some other code which finally returns an object
}
returnObj.beforeLoadComplete('records');
console.log(returnObj.summary);
```

**Update:** Added code snippet to verify that `returnObj` could be accessed via this in callback handler.

```js
var returnObj = {};
returnObj.beforeLoadComplete = function () {
  var someObj = {
    total: {
      label: "Items",
      value: "15"
    },
    additional: [{
      label: 'Item1 Total',
      value: '25000'
    }]
  };
  this.summary = someObj;
  // some other code which finally returns an object
}
//returnObj.beforeLoadComplete();

function verifyObjectUpdated(){
   alert(returnObj.summary);
}
```

```html
<select onChange="returnObj.beforeLoadComplete()">
  <option>Trigger onChange to add summary to your returnObj</option>
  <option>Trigger onChange to add summary to your returnObj</option>
</select>

<select onChange="verifyObjectUpdated()">
  <option>Trigger onChange to alert summary of returnObj ( do it after adding summary)</option>
  <option>Trigger onChange to alert summary of returnObj ( do it after adding summary)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thx a lot...But am getting "this" is undefined inside the callback

Comment: @testndtv i've added working snippets with alerts. See value of select, they describe action ... Also you could play with alert to display some particular properties of your summary object...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `this` inside your object:

```
var res = {
  foo: 'bar',
  setSmth: function(data) {
    this.summary = data
  }
}

res.setSmth({bar: 'foo'})

console.log(res.summary)
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggcj2ovm/)